# Get the lowest price from a product and the provider for that price

Tags: mysql, sql, product, min

I'm making a query for a school assignment, in which I select products which are below minimum stock, then I select the provider which delivers each product for the lowest price.

These are the tables.

`+------------+`     `+------------------+`     `+------------+`

`|  products  |`     `| product_overview |`     `|  provider  |`

`+------------+`     `+------------------+`     `+------------+`

`| productID  |`     `| productID        |`     `| providerID |`

`| name       |`     `| providerID       |`     `| name       |`

`| stock      |`     `| price            |`     `+------------+`

`| min_stock  |`     `+------------------+`

`+------------+`


This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT p.name, pr.name
FROM products p JOIN product_overview po ON p.productID = po.productID
JOIN provider l ON po.providerID = pr.providerID
WHERE p.stock < p.min_stock
GROUP BY po.productID
ORDER BY p.name;
```

I look for which products have `stock < min_stock` and then look for a provider. Currently the provider given in the output is not the provider delivering the product for the lowest price.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT p.name, pr.name provider_name, po.price
  FROM products p JOIN product_overview po ON p.productID = po.productID
  JOIN provider pr ON po.providerID = pr.providerID
 WHERE p.stock < p.min_stock
   AND not exists 
      (select 1 from product_overview poo 
        where poo.productID = po.productID 
          and poo.price < po.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use window functions:

```
SELECT pp.*
FROM (SELECT p.name as product_name, pr.name as provider_name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.productID ORDER BY po.price ASC) as seqnum
      FROM products p JOIN 
           product_overview po
           ON p.productID = po.productID JOIN
           provider pr
           ON po.providerID = pr.providerID
      WHERE p.stock < p.min_stock
     ) pp
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY p.name;
```